# Largest area of identical adjacent matrix elements

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix

> Given a 2D matrix find the largest area of identical elements.

Here is my first implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ProgrammingBasics 
{
  class MaxArrayArea
  {
    static void Main()
    {
        // target matrix
        int[,] matrix = new int[,] { { 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4 },
                                     { 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4 },
                                     { 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3 },
                                     { 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1 },
                                     { 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1,}
                                   };
        PrintMatrix(matrix);

        MaxAreaOfIdenticalAdjacentElements(matrix);
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*
        Method:  MaxAreaOfIdenticalAdjacentElements (arr2D);

    */
    static void MaxAreaOfIdenticalAdjacentElements(int[,] arr2D)
    {
        int value = 0;
        int largestArea = 0;
        HashSet<Tuple<int, int>> largestAreaElements = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr2D.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2D.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                // stores all unique matrix elements with the same values
                HashSet<Tuple<int, int>> visited = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>();

                // mark start element as visited
                Tuple<int, int> MatrixElement = new Tuple<int, int>(i, j);
                visited.Add(MatrixElement);

                CheckLeft(arr2D, i, j, visited);
                CheckRight(arr2D, i, j, visited);
                CheckUp(arr2D, i, j, visited);
                CheckDown(arr2D, i, j, visited);

                // check if area with current value is largest
                if (visited.Count > largestArea)
                {
                    value = arr2D[i, j];
                    largestArea = visited.Count;
                    largestAreaElements = visited;
                }
            }
        }

        // mark the area
        char[,] area = new char[arr2D.GetLength(0), arr2D.GetLength(1)];
        foreach (var item in largestAreaElements)
        {
            area[item.Item1, item.Item2] = '*';
        }

        PrintMatrix(area);

        // print result
        Console.WriteLine("Value: {0} Area: {1}", value, largestArea);
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*
        Method: CheckLeft (arr2D, i, j, visited);

        arr2D - target 2D matrix storing seached elements
        i - row of current element
        j - column of current element
        visited - collection holding the unique adjacent elements with same value

        It recursively checks for elements with identical values to the left, up, and down.
    */
    static void CheckLeft(int[,] arr2D, int i, int j, HashSet<Tuple<int, int>> visited)
    {
        int currentValue = arr2D[i, j];
        int col = j - 1;

        if (col < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        while (col >= 0)
        {
            Tuple<int, int> nextElement = new Tuple<int, int>(i, col);
            if (arr2D[i, col] == currentValue && !visited.Contains(nextElement))
            {
                visited.Add(nextElement);

                // check up
                CheckUp(arr2D, i, col, visited);

                // check down
                CheckDown(arr2D, i, col, visited);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            --col;
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*
        Method: CheckUp (arr2D, i, j, visited);

        arr2D - target 2D matrix storing seached elements
        i - row of current element
        j - column of current element
        visited - collection holding the unique adjacent elements with same value

        It recursively checks for elements with identical values to the up, left, and right.
    */
    static void CheckUp(int[,] arr2D, int i, int j, HashSet<Tuple<int, int>> visited)
    {
        int currentValue = arr2D[i, j];
        int row = i - 1;

        if (row < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        while (row >= 0)
        {
            Tuple<int, int> nextElement = new Tuple<int, int>(row, j);
            if (arr2D[row, j] == currentValue && !visited.Contains(nextElement))
            {
                visited.Add(nextElement);

                // check left 
                CheckLeft(arr2D, row, j, visited);

                // check right
                CheckRight(arr2D, row, j, visited);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            --row;
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*
        Method: CheckRight (arr2D, i, j, visited);

        arr2D - target 2D matrix storing seached elements
        i - row of current element
        j - column of current element
        visited - collection holding the unique adjacent elements with same value

        It recursively checks for elements with identical values to the right, up, and down.
    */
    static void CheckRight(int[,] arr2D, int i, int j, HashSet<Tuple<int, int>> visited)
    {
        int currentValue = arr2D[i, j];
        int col = j + 1;

        if (col >= arr2D.GetLength(1))
        {
            return;
        }

        while (col < arr2D.GetLength(1))
        {
            Tuple<int, int> nextElement = new Tuple<int, int>(i, col);
            if (arr2D[i, col] == currentValue && !visited.Contains(nextElement))
            {
                visited.Add(nextElement);

                // check up
                CheckUp(arr2D, i, col, visited);

                // check down
                CheckDown(arr2D, i, col, visited);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            ++col;
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*
        Method: CheckDown (arr2D, i, j, visited);

        arr2D - target 2D matrix storing seached elements
        i - row of current element
        j - column of current element
        visited - collection holding the unique adjacent elements with same value

        It recursively checks for elements with identical values to the down, left, and right.
    */
    static void CheckDown(int[,] arr2D, int i, int j, HashSet<Tuple<int, int>> visited)
    {
        int currentValue = arr2D[i, j];
        int row = i + 1;

        if (row >= arr2D.GetLength(0))
        {
            return;
        }

        while (row < arr2D.GetLength(0))
        {
            Tuple<int, int> nextElement = new Tuple<int, int>(row, j);
            if (arr2D[row, j] == currentValue && !visited.Contains(nextElement))
            {
                visited.Add(nextElement);

                // check left
                CheckLeft(arr2D, row, j, visited);

                // check right
                CheckRight(arr2D, row, j, visited);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            ++row;
        }
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*
        Method: PrintMatrix(arr);

        It prints all the elements of the 2D integer array.
    */
    static void PrintMatrix(int[,] arr)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < arr.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < arr.GetLength(1); column++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,3} ", arr[row, column]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*
        Method: PrintMatrix(arr);

        It prints all the elements of the 2D char array.
    */
    static void PrintMatrix(char[,] arr)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < arr.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < arr.GetLength(1); column++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,3} ", arr[row, column]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Any constructive criticism will be greatly appreciated, especially regarding the reduction of the algorithm complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any constructive criticism will be greatly appreciated, especially regarding the reduction of the algorithm complexity.

Rather than doing a line-by-line review of your code, let me suggest a general problem-solving technique. Sometimes you get nicer code by solving the more general problem, and then applying your general solution to a specific problem.

Suppose we have an interface:

```
interface IGraph<T> where T : IEquatable<T> 
{
  IEnumerable<T> Nodes { get; }
  IEnumerable<T> Neighbors(T t);
}
```

That is, a graph is a thing that has a collection of nodes, and every node has a collection of nodes that it is "beside".

Can you write this method?

```
IEnumerable<T> Reachable(IGraph<T> graph, T start)
```

That is, given a graph and a node, return the set of nodes that is "reachable" starting at the start node.

Can you write this method?

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Partitions(IGraph<T> graph)
```

That is, given a graph, return a sequence where each element in the sequence is a collection of nodes that are *all reachable from each other*.  That is, the *transitive and reflexive closure of reachability.*

And can you write this method?

```
IGraph<MyNode> ArrayToGraph(int[,] array)
```

That is, the method takes in an array and returns a graph of `MyNode` where two nodes are neighbours if they are neighbours in the array *and have the same value*.

If you can write those three methods then the solution to your problem is a one-liner:

```
int max = Partitions(ArrayToGraph(arr)).Select(p => p.Count()).Max();
```

*When you solve the more general problem, the code to solve the more specific problem becomes very short and easy to understand.*

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. That is a great step-by-step explanation (of what I've understood) on how to build a graph out of the existing array and then to find the largest sequence (2D structure) of connected nodes with same value. That is actually beautiful and I will try to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd prefer to use this alias:

```
using Path = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<System.Tuple<int, int>>;
```

Next, it makes sense to store a boolean flag for each matrix element indicating that this element has already been visited.

```
bool[,] visited = new bool[nx, ny];
```

And the last, I believe four methods `CheckUp`, `CheckDown`, `CheckLeft` and `CheckRight` could be combined into a single one.

```
private static void CheckAdjacent(int[,] arr2D, int i, int j, bool[,] visited,
                                  HashSet<Tuple<int, int>> path)
```

Here is the resulting code:

```
private static void MaxAreaOfIdenticalAdjacentElements(int[,] arr2D)
{
    int nx = arr2D.GetLength(0);
    int ny = arr2D.GetLength(1);

    int value = 0;
    int largestArea = 0;
    bool[,] visited = new bool[nx, ny];

    Path largestAreaElements = new Path();

    for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
        {
            if (visited[i, j])
                continue;

            Path path = new Path();

            CheckAdjacent(arr2D, i, j, visited, path);

            // check if area with current value is largest
            if (path.Count > largestArea)
            {
                value = arr2D[i, j];
                largestArea = path.Count;
                largestAreaElements = path;
            }
        }
    }

    // mark the area
    char[,] area = new char[nx, ny];
    foreach (var item in largestAreaElements)
    {
        area[item.Item1, item.Item2] = '*';
    }

    PrintMatrix(area);

    // print result
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0} Area: {1}", value, largestArea);
}

private static void CheckAdjacent(int[,] arr2D, int i, int j, bool[,] visited,
                                  HashSet<Tuple<int, int>> path)
{
    int currentValue = arr2D[i, j];
    path.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i, j));
    visited[i, j] = true;

    // Check up
    if (i > 0 && !visited[i - 1, j] && arr2D[i - 1, j] == currentValue)
        CheckAdjacent(arr2D, i - 1, j, visited, path);

    // Check down
    if (i < arr2D.GetLength(0) - 1 && !visited[i + 1, j] && arr2D[i + 1, j] == currentValue)
        CheckAdjacent(arr2D, i + 1, j, visited, path);

    // Check left
    if (j > 0 && !visited[i, j - 1] && arr2D[i, j - 1] == currentValue)
        CheckAdjacent(arr2D, i, j - 1, visited, path);

    // Check right
    if (j < arr2D.GetLength(1) - 1 && !visited[i, j + 1] && arr2D[i, j + 1] == currentValue)
        CheckAdjacent(arr2D, i, j + 1, visited, path);
}
```